# can I simplify this "delayed" python generator?

Tags: python, generator

I want a generator that returns what I sent to it in the *following* iteration:

```
>>>g = delayed_generator()
>>>g.send(None)

>>>g.send('this')

>>>g.send('is')
'this'
>>>g.send('delayed')
'is'
>>>g.send('!')
'delayed'
```

I've come up with a solution that involves three internal variables and I'm wondering if there is a simpler way of doing it. This is my solution:

```
def delayed_generator():
    y = None
    z = None
    while True:
        x = yield y
        y=x
        y = yield z
        z=y
        z = yield x
        x=z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a queue:

```
def delayed_generator():
     q = [None, None]
     while True:
         x = yield q.pop(0)
         q.append(x)

g = delayed_generator()
g.send(None), g.send('this'), g.send('is'), g.send('delayed'), g.send('!')
```

returns

```
(None, None, 'this', 'is', 'delayed')
```